# Validating multiple files before uploading in Django

Tags: python, django, django-validation, django-file-upload

I am currently trying to create a Django app that allows a user to upload multiple .gpx files at once. I would like that when the files are validated the user is provided with a list of files and the reason they weren't uploaded.

The file is validated by the following:

File size

File type

Has this file been uploaded before (based on hash of file)

If the user uploads a single file that fails any of the above they get the correct error message. If they upload 2 or more files which have an error they only get the message for the first error that occurs.

here is my form.py:

```
from django import forms

from .validators import validate_file

class UploadGpxForm(forms.Form):
    gpx_file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(
        attrs={'multiple': True}), 
        validators=[validate_file]
        )
```

here is my validators.py:

```
from hashlib import md5

from .models import gpxTrack

from django.conf import settings
from django.template.defaultfilters import filesizeformat
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

def validate_file(value):
    if len(value.name.split('.')) != 2:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(file_name)s has not been uploaded: File type is not supported') 
            , params = { 'file_name': value.name }
            , code = 'file_type'
            )
    if value.content_type in settings.DASHBOARD_UPLOAD_FILE_TYPES:
        if value._size > settings.DASHBOARD_UPLOAD_FILE_MAX_SIZE:
            raise ValidationError(
                _('%(file_name)s has not been uploaded: File too big.'\
                'Please keep filesize under %(setting_size)s.'\
                'Current filesize %(file_size)s') ,
                params = { 
                    'file_name': value.name,
                    'setting_size': filesizeformat(settings.DASHBOARD_UPLOAD_FILE_MAX_SIZE),
                    'file_size': filesizeformat(value._size)
                    },
                code = 'file_size'
                    )
    else:
        raise ValidationError(
            _('%(file_name)s has not been uploaded: File type is not supported')
             , params = { 'file_name' : value.name }
             , code = 'file_type'
             )


    #generate MD5
    md5hash = md5()
    for chunk in value.chunks():
        md5hash.update(chunk)
    file_hash = md5hash.hexdigest()
    if gpxTrack.objects.filter(file_hash=file_hash).exists():
        raise ValidationError(_('%s has already been uploaded') % (value.name))
```

Here's my model.py:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from django.contrib.gis import admin as geoadmin

class gpxTrack(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-start']

    track = models.MultiLineStringField()
    file_hash = models.CharField("md5 hash value", max_length=32, unique=True)
    start = models.DateTimeField("Start date and time", blank=True, null=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.start.strftime("%a %p %-d %B %Y")
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking for help on? Does something in the code you provide not work?

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I'm looking to try get a list of files that haven't passed validation and then pass that to the user.

Comment: Can you try implementing a `clean` function rather than assigning  `validators`? With the `clean` function you'll be able to loop through the files individually and raise multiple errors: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/validation/#raising-multiple-errors

Comment: Thanks, that does seem easier. So I just create a list with lots of ValidationError tuples and then pass that to a ValidationError that I actually raise?